# read derived type from .net dll

Tags: c#, reflection

**Demo:**
I have two class library in my project. 1) Action 2) Process.

My **Action Library** contains a **interface IProcessor** with a **method Process.**

In my Process Library i have 3 classes

**A) ClassA :IProcessor

B) ClassB :IProcessor

C) ClassC :IProcessor**

which implements the IProcessor interface.

When i tried to read Process Library's assembly  I did not fine any type of ClassA , ClassB, and ClassC

I used

```
Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(process.dll);
Type submitOfferType = processorAssembly.GetType("Namespace.ClassA");
```

to read type from assembly.

**how do get derived type from dll?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFrom` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile`. Try this:

```
Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("[...]process.dll"));
Type submitOfferType = processorAssembly.GetType("Namespace.ClassA");
```

`Assembly.LoadFile` will not attempt to resolve dependancies relative to the file your loading with `LoadFile` so it won't even try to resolve your action library. Appearanly it will solve it's problem of not being able to load the types becouse of dependencies by simply ignoring them.

Comment: Peter now I am not able to call the method implemented from Interface

Answer (score 2):

Change this to:

```
Type submitOfferType = 
    processorAssembly.GetType("NamespaceOfProcessLibrary.ClassA");
```

[Assembly.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) requires the *full name* of the class.

Comment: I tried with namespace also but dint work. Its not showing .GetTypes() returned in list also

Comment: @Pramod: Which classes are shown in GetTypes and which are not? Can you see a pattern here?

Comment: the classes which are not derived from IProcessor interface are displayed in list and those are inherited not showing in GetTypes() returned list

Answer (score 0):

[`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) expects the type's full name. This means you must include the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the exact full name of "ClassA":

```
Assembly processorAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(process.dll);
var types= processorAssembly.GetTypes();
```

Check the name of the "types" in the debugger to get the real name.